# How to Integrate Component Help Files into the Delphi system?

Tags: delphi, chm, winhelp

How do you integrate component help files into the Delphi 2006 help system so
that the help is avaliable when pressing F1.  The help files are in hlp and chm format.

Comment: For Delphi 2007, I found [this article](http://chrisbensen.blogspot.com/2007/04/integrating-3rd-party-help-into-delphi.html "Integrating 3rd Party Help Into Delphi 2007").

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Delphi 2006 uses HTML Help 2 (as do D2007 and D2009), and therefore the IDE has no knowledge of HTML Help 1 files.

You can either create a Tools menu item in the IDE to launch the CHM help file and then do a search in it, or create a desktop shortcut to it. Neither of these will give you F1 context-sensitive help, however.